# Rails - ArgumentError in BookingsController#create, Can't multiply a Money by a NilClass's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I'm getting the error code above in my Rails app when attempting to implement a payment/reservation process which allows a user to be able to book & pay for spaces on an event. 
Previously my code would only allow for a user to pay for one event space at a time. My code below is an attempt for a user to be able to pay for any number of spaces they require, subject to availability.
This is my model code -

**Booking.rb**

```
   class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user

    validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates :event, presence: true, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

    before_save :set_price_to_zero_if_free

    def set_price_to_zero_if_free
       self.event.price >= 1    unless self.event.is_free
    end

    def reserve(stripe_token)
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        #if valid?

                # Free events don't need to do anything special
                if event.is_free?
                save!

                # Paid events should charge the customer's card
                else

                    begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price * quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end
            end 
        #end
    end
end
```

And controller -

**bookings_controller.rb**

```
    class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f


    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

            if 
                @booking.reserve(booking_params['stripe_token'])
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                redirect_to event_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end


    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end



end
```

I'm pretty sure this points to 'quality' having a nil value. What I'm unclear on is why the validation hasn't sorted this out? What else could be causing this and if the validation isn't working, why not?

Here's my Booking table in my schema. Do I need to add a default value here? How do I do the migration to add a default value? -

```
  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "stripe_token"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.integer  "total_amount"
    t.string   "stripe_charge_id"
  end
```

Comment: Without seeing your controller code, it's impossible to say for sure, but I strongly your validations haven't run *yet*, because you haven't done anything yet that triggers validations. Validations are only run when you try to save a record, if you explicitly call the `valid?` method, situations like that.

Comment: I've just added controller. I'm intrigued by your views - could you explain a little more what you mean, please?

Answer (score 0):

In `BookingsController#create`, on  you call `@event.bookings.new(bookings_params)`. This creates a new `Booking` *object* in memory, but it doesn't yet create a `Booking` *record* in the database. It's always perfectly valid to call `Model.new()` with no arguments, even if you have plenty of validations; you'll just receive a model object that isn't valid. You can then do what you like with it, such as calling methods on it, setting attributes, checking to see if it *is* valid (with the `valid?` method), etc. As long as you've made it valid before you call `save` (or `save!`), everything is fine as far as the model object is concerned.

So when, a few lines later, you call `@booking.reserve(booking_params['stripe_token'])`, which in turn calls `event.price * quantity`, you have no guarantee that `quantity` is not nil (or even "apple") because you haven't performed validations yet.

There are a couple of ways you can work through this; the simplest would just be to check `self.valid?` from within `Booking#reserve`, before you do anything else with it.

Comment: Where exactly do I do this? I've placed it under def reserve(booking_params) and I'm getting the same error. Do I need to make a @booking.reserve call in the controller?

Comment: You already have a call to `@booking.reserve` in the controller. That said, the `ActiveRecord::Base#valid?` doesn't raise exceptions, it just returns `true` or `false`, so, you need something like `if self.valid? proceed with the reservation else throw a fit end`. You could also just `save!` the booking record before even attempting to process the reservation, though that may require you to re-think other aspects of your workflow.